# How to save Enum object with field value by jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
public enum AssesmentType {
    PERCENTAGE,PERCENTILE;



    enter code here
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for 100% what you mean, but i think you want the following:

The variable in the jpa-entity remains a String (containing the value from the database)

in the getter you can return a `AssesmentType` with `return AssesmentType.fromString(jpaValue)`

in the setter you take a `AssesmentType` and set the .getValue() into the String.

```
public enum AssesmentType {
PERCENTAGE("1"),PERCENTILE("2");
private String value;

private static final Map<String, AssesmentType stringMap 
        = new HashMap<String, AssesmentType ();

static {
    for (AssesmentType  b : AssesmentType .values()) {
        stringMap.put(b.getValue(),b);          
    }
}

AssesmentType(String value){
  this.value = value;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public AssesmentType fromString(String value) {
    return stringMap.get(value);
}

}
```